# How to align text to the right on an xul listbox column?

Tags: css, firefox-addon, xul

In my firefox xul window, I have a listbox.  I need the first column to be right-aligned and the second to be left-aligned.  I tried adding `text-align:right;` to the css, or directly in the xul, `text-align="right"` but neither had any effect.

How do I do this?  Does anyone know how to align the text in a column of `listbox` cells?
Here is my xul:

```
<vbox>
  <listbox id="listbox1" rows="15">
    <listhead><listheader label="&col1;"/><listheader label="&col2;"/></listhead>
    <listcols><listcol width="75"/><listcol flex="1"/></listcols>
    <listitem><listcell class="column1" label="&row1text;"/>    <listcell label="&row1btext;"/>     </listitem>
    <listitem><listcell class="column1" label="&row2text;"/>    <listcell label="&row2btext;"/>     </listitem>
  </listbox>            
</vbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  this I hope this will help for you.

```
align="right"
```

Comment: Nope.  I don't know how that would work anyway.  I need the text-align on the contents of the cells - and it is a `listbox` control, not a table.

Answer (score 0):

Is there something special with your xul?

The following css should work

```css
listcell {text-align:right;}
listcell+listcell {text-align:left;}
```

Comment: If there is somethings special, I don't know what it would be.  I pasted this into the css file and it doesn't have any effect.  The css file is properly defined in the xul. I'll post some code.

Comment: Very odd. Have you checked the error console? I suspect there is something (a typo maybe) that breaks the stylesheet.

Comment: If there is, it doesn't say so. The only thing I can think of is that I use Javascript to set the labels in the cells. Maybe somehow that clears the text alignment?